# can not loop tab assoc for revever key and data

Tags: php

I have a table json and I will get the key of the table files, I do like that but it does not work

i want received

1./home/ke/Test-Code/CODE.php

2. [message] => Missing file doc comment

3.[source] => PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.Missing

```
$var = json_decode($data, true);
//print_r($var);
foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        print_r($key);
    }
}
$var = json_decode($data, true);
//print_r($var);
foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        print_r($key);
    }
}
```

**here is my tab json**

```
Array
(
    [totals] => Array
        (
            [errors] => 2
            [warnings] => 0
            [fixable] => 0
        )

    [files] => Array
        (
            [/home/ke/Test-Code/CODE.php] => Array
                (
                    [errors] => 2
                    [warnings] => 0
                    [messages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [message] => Missing file doc comment
                                    [source] => PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.Missing
                                    [severity] => 5
                                    [type] => ERROR
                                    [line] => 2
                                    [column] => 1
                                    [fixable] => 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [message] => Expected "for (...) {\n"; found "for (...)\n{\n"
                                    [source] => PEAR.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.Found
                                    [severity] => 5
                                    [type] => ERROR
                                    [line] => 12
                                    [column] => 1
                                    [fixable] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I can't work out what your question is. What data are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: i want receve /home/ke/Test-Code/CODE.php and 

[message] => Missing file doc comment

[source] => PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.Missing

Comment: So assuming `/home/ke/Test-Code/CODE.php` is unknown when the code runs, you need a couple of foreach, nested. e.g. `foreach($var['files'] as $file) { foreach($file['messages'] as $message) { echo $message['source']; } }`

Comment: @Jonnix it's not the data that I'm getting to get that answer it gives
totals
PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.Missing
PEAR.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.Found
//totlas does not contain this data

files
PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.Missing
PEAR.ControlStructures.ControlSignature.Found

but I'm here to recover /home/ke/Test-Code/CODE.php

Comment: @samiake01 I'm afraid that made zero sense to me.

Comment: @Jonnix thank you it works , but data /home/ke/Test-Code/CODE.php i can't recoved

Comment: Oh, you want the file name too? Change `foreach($var['files'] as $file)` to `foreach($var['files'] as $filePath => $file)` and it'lll be available in `$filePath`.